# How to add an item in Listview adapter Linear Layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I know how to populate listview and I know how to make custom adapter.
I want to add View inside Linear layout of rowLayout of ListView.
Here is MyList Adapter.

***I want a listview which each item layout is created runtime But I can not achieve this.***

This code is working without ListView but when I add it to Linearlayout inside listview .It Gives me error.

```
public class KmapListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    List<KmapModel> mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<KmapModel>();


    public KmapListAdapter(Context activity, List<KmapModel> kmapModelList) {

        this.context = activity;
        this.mOriginalValues = kmapModelList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
if(mOriginalValues == null)
    return  0;
        return mOriginalValues.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return mOriginalValues.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    ViewHolder Holder ;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        KmapModel kmapModel;
        if (layoutInflater == null)
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            Holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
            Holder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_matrix_1);

            convertView.setTag(Holder);

        } else
            Holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        kmapModel = mOriginalValues.get(position);
        Holder.linearLayout.addView(kmapModel.getLinearLayout());
        return convertView;
    }




    static class ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout linearLayout;}}
```

And it is my Model List

```
 public List<KmapModel> ListViewOneItem( int ROWS, int COLS) {

        String[][] KmapArray = KMapMaker(ROWS, COLS);
        //  Log.v("Kmap array",""+KmapArray);
        TextView[][] KmapTextView = new TextView[KmapArray.length][KmapArray[0].length];

        int temp = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < KmapArray.length; i++) {
            KmapModel kmapModel = new KmapModel();
            LinearLayout rowLinearLayout = makeRowLinearLayout();


            for (int j = 0; j < KmapArray[0].length; j++) {

                TextView rowTextView = makeTextView();
                rowTextView.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);


                rowLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);
                KmapTextView[i][j] = rowTextView;// Add a text view in a jagged array for later use

            }
            kmapModel.setLinearLayout(rowLinearLayout);
            kmapModelList.add(kmapModel);


        }
        return  kmapModelList;
    }
```

Now I got an Error

**The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**
on  this line

```
 Holder.linearLayout.addView(kmapModel.getLinearLayout());
```

Q1) How to resolve this Problem 
Q2) Why I am getting this issue?

Thanks @pskink he give me a way I try Then I upload Solution.

Comment: Please Help me If qustion is Wrong Please tell me.

Comment: Kindly Help me What can I do I am stuck on this 
I want a listview which each item layout is created runtime
But I can not achieve this

Comment: If question is not make sense please give me suggestion.

Comment: **"The specified child already has a parent"** what is unclear in this?

Comment: My question is what can i do please suggest me it is possible or not

Comment: what you can do? add a child view that has no parent, that is: it was not added to any other parent view before

Comment: @pskink can you give some code example.Please I am noob in android

Comment: TextView newChildView = new TextView(ctx); newChildView.setText("bla bla bla"); Holder.linearLayout.addView(newChildView);

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738799/adding-dynamic-linear-layouts-to-a-list-view) might help u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The specified child already has a parent.

Stop trying to give the child a second parent. All views are from broken homes. They have one parent.

You can add views to views, you cannot add views that are already added. This causes loops and loops are loopy. And to successfully iterate the viewtree it needs to be a tree. So views get one and only one parent. Either clear out the layout you already have and use that or add a new view to the layout or basically anything you want that doesn't involve using the same object in several places in the view tree.

Comment: Thanks you say We can not add herarichal parents

Answer (score 1):

Now Finally I found A good Solution After Resaeaching.

Thanks everyone Who contribute.
This my List Adapter  and I get what i want

```
public class KmapListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    List<KmapModel> mOriginalValues;


    public KmapListAdapter(Activity activity, List<KmapModel> kmapModelList) {

        this.context = activity;
        this.mOriginalValues = kmapModelList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        Log.d("SIZEOF",""+mOriginalValues.size());
        return mOriginalValues.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return mOriginalValues.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    ViewHolder Holder;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (layoutInflater == null)
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            Holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
            Holder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_matrix);

            convertView.setTag(Holder);



        LinearLayout rowLinearLayout = makeRowLinearLayout();
        Holder.linearLayout.addView(rowLinearLayout);
        KmapModel kmapModel = new KmapModel();
         kmapModel  = mOriginalValues.get(position);
         String[] array = kmapModel.getKmapString();
        for (int i=0 ; i< array.length;i++)
        {
            TextView rowTextView = makeTextView();
            rowTextView.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            rowTextView.setText(""+array[i]);
           rowLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);

        }




        return convertView;
    }

    public TextView makeTextView() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 80);
        lparams.setMargins(7, 0, 7, 0);

        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        tv.setTextSize((float) 17);
        tv.setMaxLines(10);

        tv.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext_selector_background));
        return tv;
    }


    public LinearLayout makeRowLinearLayout() {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


        return linearLayout;
    } // End of makeRowLinearLayout()

    static class ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout linearLayout;


    }


}
```

**Edit**

We can't add a view to a view that is already added somewhere. Remove the old view, and add a new view, or reuse the old view by removing all the stuff from it. But, there is no adding an already added view to the viewtree again.

Comment: if anyone has issue similar to  this feel free to ask