# add value in listview android

Tags: android

I have a EditText, ListView and Button.

My requirement is on click of the button, I wanted the text from edittext to append in the list.

- I want the code on button click.
- I tried and I get unsupported error.

Can anybody help me in solving this issue?

Comment: There are sooo many different ways to do this. Post your code!

Comment: Post some possible code of button click listener if you have tried.

Comment: i think you have to do some googling before post here: check this links : http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998483/listview-dynamic-add-item

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar That's not his requirement I think. 2nd link will help him out I think.

Comment: @PareshMayani : he said "My requirement is on click of the button, I wanted the text from edittext to append in the list." --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/10296747/1168654

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to Activity.onCreate():

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Add this code to Button's OnClickListener:

```
String text = eidtText.getText().toString();
adapter.add(text);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```