# Android Listview with EditText and TextView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, textview

I have a Listview with `EditText` and TextViews for existing users. I'm using the EditText to adding a new user. How can I add the new user via EditText after entering a name? The result should appear in the ListView as next! [enter image description here][1].

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.savelistviewadapter, null);

        holder.username = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        holder.newuser = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.newuser);
        holder.radiosave = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radiosaveuser);
       // holder.img = (ImageView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.temperrr);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    ItemBean bean = (ItemBean) itemList.get(position);

   // holder.imgViewLogo.setBackgroundResource(bean.getImage());
    holder.username.setText(bean.getTitle());
    if(holder.newuser.getText().toString().length()>0)
    {
    holder.username.setText(holder.newuser.getText().toString());
    }
   // holder.txtViewDescription.setText(bean.getDescription());
   // holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_download);
   if(position==getCount()-1)
   {
       holder.newuser.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
   }
   else
   {
       holder.newuser.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
   }
    return convertView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView mListView;
EditText mValue;
Button mAdd;

List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_listview);

    data.add("Hello World");

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
    mValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_to_add);
    mAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_string);

    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));
    mAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View currentView) {
            data.add(new String(mValue.getText().toString()));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How to create next row on the list view.?

Comment: check this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998483/listview-dynamic-add-item

Comment: I have custom rows where should i inflate those rows.?

Comment: so, it means you have custom listview.??

Comment: first change your image above.. its not look like what you want.. so i can understand what you exactly want..

Comment: Hey that existing user1 and existing user 2 are textviews that +new user is edittext.. when a user type a user name in the edit text the name should store to the list view as next row . suppose I entered a name(devian) in the edittext then the lisview will be ,Existing user 1 Existing user 2 devian and final row as +new user

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31391/discussion-between-segi-and-devian)